# How to append all items in the list?

Tags: python, object-detection

I need to write image_ids in a file which exist in mmdetection class . i tried to get the image_id by `img_meta['ori_filename']` and implement this code to write all of the ids

```
        data1=[]
        data1.append(img_meta['ori_filename'])
        f=open('file.txt','w')
        for i in data1:  
             f.write(i)
```

but it write only one image . it couldn't append all the images i have

Comment: you have to keep this block of code inside a loop and then append all the `ori_filename` in the `data1` array

Comment: I don't see the above snippet in the GitHub repository you provided.

Comment: i put the link under your answer post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a variable `image_metas` where all the images are stored.

```
data1=[]
for img_meta in image_metas:
    data1.append(img_meta['ori_filename'])
f=open('file.txt','w')
for i in data1:  
     f.write(i)
```

Comment: yes but i couldn't  catch the container of images , can you please take a look at the code https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/blob/master/mmdet/apis/test.py

Comment: where did you declared the `data1` variable

Comment: `for i, (img, img_meta) in enumerate(zip(imgs, img_metas)):` this is the loop I guess

Comment: Cound not find the post.  Please check the link.